# creating a new variable depending on value of 2 others in R-code

Tags: r, variables

I would like to create a new categorical variable that measures whether or not a student is a 1st generation university student.

variable X is mother's education 1=less than HS, 2 = HS or GED, 3 = BS/BA, 4 = Masters, 5 = PHD

variable Y is father's education and is measured the same way.

I would like to create variable Z such that if both mother and father have never received anything above their bachelor's or above, then variable Z would be 1, if not variable Z will be 0.

Thanks so much!

Comment: Something like `DF$Z <- with(DF, +( max(X,Y) <= 3 ))`

Comment: @Frank I guess you should use `pmax` instead of `max`. Another concise way would be `DF$Z <-+(do.call(pmax,df)<=3)`

Comment: @nicola, that works. I was modifying @Frank's and I wrote `DF$Z <- 0 + (apply(DF, 1, max ) <= 3)`.

Comment: @MartínEscarrá `apply` should be avoided, since it is slower than vectorized functions like `pmax`.

Comment: @nicola Yup, you're right.

Answer (score 0):

Tough to give a concrete answer without a concrete example, but assuming X and Y are columns in a data.frame and are treated numerically (i.e. instead of factors), this should work:

```
df <- data.frame(X=sample(1:5, 10, replace=T), Y = sample(1:5, 10, replace=T))
sapply(1:nrow(df), function(i) as.numeric(max(df$X[i], df$Y[i]) <= 3))
```